# RecyclerView recreating ViewHolder instead of rebinding

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

Basically I have a `RecyclerView` with chat messages. The scenario is as follows:

1. I add a single message -> Causes `RecyclerView` to add a new `ViewHolder`
2. Delay of about 2 seconds
3. I change the first message and add a new one -> Should cause `RecyclerView` to rebind the first message and create a new `ViewHolder` for the second one.

My problem lies in step 3. as the first `ViewHolder` is removed and a new one is created and then bound. This produces a very slight flickering which is a little bit annoying and all in all this shouldn't happen.

I am using `DiffUtil` to dispatch changes, the whole setup is a little bit more involved so it is hard to describe the whole picture but I narrowed it down to this:

The `DiffUtil` produces the correct result and calls `onItemRangeChanged` for the first item and `onItemRangeInserted` for the second item. For whatever reason the first ViewHolder is then removed and a new on is created, added and then bound.

Did somebody experienced similar behaviour or has a clue why this could be the case? I tried to debug through the `RecyclerView` code but it is a nightmare and I still don't understand the whole thing. What could be the reason that the first `ViewHolder` cannot be rebound and a new one has to be created?

If I can provide any more information just ask for it and I will try my best.

A small repository showing the problem can be found here: https://github.com/MaxGierlachowski/recyclerview_viewholder_bug

If you look into the error logs and look at the 4th "MESSAGE" log you see that a onChanged and a onInserted are dispatched to the adapter but there is a new ViewHolder created for the onChanged one. I know that RecyclerView checks for a lot of things like animation completion and so on but I really would like to know why the ViewHolder isn't rebound but recreated.

EDIT:
Something I figured out was that if that `createViewHolder` is called by the `RecyclerView` the ViewHolder that should be reused is inside the `mChangedScrap` list and `mState.isPreLayout()` is false so the function `tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline()` doesn't search the `mChangedScrap` list and creates a new one. Still this shouldn't happen, the `ViewHolder` isn't even animated or something and it seems like all animations are finished at that point.

Small video of the flickering:
[image: flickering effect]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hey so I figured it out myself but I still don't fully understand why this is necessary. So the `ItemAnimator` inside `RecyclerView` decides whether a changed ViewHolder will be just rebound or recreated. It will decide it on three factors that are mentioned in the article below. So basically because I was using the `DiffUtil` I just had to provide some arbitrary to the `onItemRangeChanged` call and it would reuse the `ViewHolder` instead of creating a new one.

It was this article that help me understand the problem:
https://medium.com/android-news/anatomy-of-recyclerview-part-1-a-search-for-a-viewholder-continued-d81c631a2b91

Answer (score 1):

Probably you have a problem with your `DiffUtil.Callback`. From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/DiffUtil.ItemCallback), there is a method `areItemsTheSame(T oldItem, T newItem)` based on the result diff util could remove and add new holder or just update the content of existing holder. Make sure that your implementation is right.

**areItemsTheSame** -> check for example that left and right holders are the same types of holders.
**areContentsTheSame** -> here you should check for equality. `object1.equals(object2)`

Comment: As I already said DiffUtil just calls onItemRangeChanged, onItemRangeInserted, ... on the adapter, an I already observed that it calls onItemRangeChanged for the first item and onItemRangeInserted for the second item. This is how it should be.

Comment: That isn't that easy because I am not allowed to publish the whole project, and the code thats related to the RecyclerView has a lot of parts. I will try to create a small project that recreates the problem and than publish this and an come back here.

Comment: Hey I just added a repository showing the problem.