# Why is DefaultItemAnimator forcing changed ViewHolders to recreate?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

Hey so basically I run into a issue with `RecyclerView` lately (The issue I had is described here: [RecyclerView recreating ViewHolder instead of rebinding](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66248856/4770659)). What I discovered was that the `ItemAnimator` inside `RecyclerView` decides if a changed `ViewHolder` just has to be rebound or a new ViewHolder should be created and crossfaded.

This article explains some of the things:
https://medium.com/android-news/anatomy-of-recyclerview-part-1-a-search-for-a-viewholder-continued-d81c631a2b91

I assume this is the part of the DefaultItemAnimator that decides what should happen:

```
     /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     * <p>
     * If the payload list is not empty, DefaultItemAnimator returns <code>true</code>.
     * When this is the case:
     * <ul>
     * <li>If you override {@link #animateChange(RecyclerView.ViewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder, int, int, int, int)}, both
     * ViewHolder arguments will be the same instance.
     * </li>
     * <li>
     * If you are not overriding {@link #animateChange(RecyclerView.ViewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder, int, int, int, int)},
     * then DefaultItemAnimator will call {@link #animateMove(RecyclerView.ViewHolder, int, int, int, int)} and
     * run a move animation instead.
     * </li>
     * </ul>
     */
    @Override
    public boolean canReuseUpdatedViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder,
            @NonNull List<Object> payloads) {
        return !payloads.isEmpty() || super.canReuseUpdatedViewHolder(viewHolder, payloads);
    }
```

Now the solution to my problem was to just call `onItemRangeChanged()` with some arbitrary payload and it would always reuse the `ViewHolder`.

**My question:**
Now I was wondering why and when it would be better to recreate the whole `ViewHolder` and crossfade it than just updating a specific part of it? In the crossreferenced problem mentioned above I was just changing the visibility of a small part of the ViewHolder but the whole things was recreated, which - I assume - is way worse performance wise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember `RecyclerView` can have multiple item view types. When `notifyItemChanged` causes view type to change then viewholders are ineligible for reuse regardless of payload.

By replacing viewholders animator maintains unified behavior in this case.

Also by updating the ViewHolder they will not undergo adapters `onViewAttachedToWindow(holder)` which people might expect while new items are being laid out and `onViewRecycled(holder)` & `onViewDetachedFromWindow(holder)` which are called for items that are being removed.

As a side note if you're experiencing `onCreateViewHolder` calls during your subsequent range updates (without payload) you should probably increase size of your [`RecyclerView.RecycledViewPool`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.RecycledViewPool).

Comment: Hey so thanks for the answer. Ok I am fine if the RecyclerView needs to do this in order to preserve uniformity but there are two problems: If the ViewHolder is completely replaced there is a slight flickering (see video in referenced question) and how am I supposed to animate changes to the state inside the view? The ViewHolder is completely recreated and all the old state of the View is lost?

Comment: @MaxGierlachowski if you're animating changes then do provide a change payload and override `onBindViewHolder(holder, position, payloads)` to consume it. Recyclerview assumes that change without payloads means item was replaced completely by another item so it just swaps viewholder instead of trying to alter it.