# DefaultItemAnimator#animateChange always called with oldHolder === newHolder

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-animation

I'm trying to implement custom change animation (`animateChange`) of `RecyclerView` items.

Problem I'm struggling to solve is that the `animateChange` is not called with 2 different instances of `oldHolder` and `newHolder`, but instead it is invoked with a single (already changed) instance of `ViewHolder` (both `oldHolder` and `newHolder` reference it). Unfortunately, this greatly complicates implementation of my animation.

### Question

How to configure `RecyclerView` (and other relevant components like `Adapter`, `ItemAnimator`, `LayoutManager`, etc.) to make the framework invoke `animateChange` with 2 instance of `ViewHolder` (one for pre-layout and one for post-layout)?

### My ItemAnimator

I've ensured that the `canReuseUpdatedViewHolder` returns `false` which should (according) to the docs force creation of new `ViewHolder` prior to `animateChange` invocation (or at least that's how I understand it).

```
    myRecyclerView.itemAnimator = object : DefaultItemAnimator() {
        
        override fun canReuseUpdatedViewHolder(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder) = false
        
        override fun animateChange(
            oldHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
            newHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
            preLayoutInfo: ItemHolderInfo,
            postLayoutInfo: ItemHolderInfo
        ): Boolean {
        
            // my anim impl here

            // oldHolder === newHolder at time of this method invocation.
            // However I'd like oldHolder to reference View in its pre-layout state.
            // How to achieve this?
        
            return false
        }
        
    }
```

### My Adapter

I've ensured that `MyAdapter` has "stable IDs" and that it properly overrides `getItemId(int)`.

```
    myRecyclerView.adapter = MyAdapter() {
        
        init {
            hasStableIds(true)
        }
        
        fun getItemId(position: Int) = ...
        
        ...
    }
```

I've also ensured, that:

1. ... that the `Adapter` doesn't override the "payload" version of `onBindViewHolder`, but rather it's non-payload version (`onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int)`). According to [some discussions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66398140/why-is-defaultitemanimator-forcing-changed-viewholders-to-recreate) this might also prevent creation of new `ViewHolder` instance.
2. ... that after data are updated the adapter is notified with `notifyDataSetChanged`:

   ```
    open fun setMyData(myData: List<MyDataType>) {
        this.myData = myData
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
   ```
3. ... that the `Adapter.getItemViewType(Int)` keep the type intact after the data are changed.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolved the issue.

The problematic part is invocation of `notifyDataSetChanged`:

```
open fun setMyData(myData: List<MyDataType>) {
    this.myData = myData
    notifyDataSetChanged()        // option 1.
    //notifyItemRangeChanged(...) // option 2.
}
```

The behavior is following:

1. For `notifyDataSetChanged` the `ItemAnimator.animateChange(...)` is invoked with single (and already updated/post-layout) instance of `ViewHolder`.
2. However, the call of `notifyItemRangeChanged` instead of `notifyDataSetChanged` causes the `ItemAnimator.animateChange(...)` to be invoked with 2 instances of `ViewHolder`, one for pre-layout (`oldHolder`) and one for post-layout (`newHolder`).

I ended up with utilizing [DiffUtil](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/DiffUtil) to properly call the corresponding `notify*` method for each list item.